# Probability of 4 parents sharing 2 birthdays

Tags: probability, birthday

I'm a math idiot and I'm trying to figure something out. My mother was born on April 10th as was my friend's mother. My father was born on July 4th as was my friend's father.

How do I calculate the probability of that happening?

**EDIT:** How would one calculate the probability of 2 pairs of shared birthdays? I think this is the answer I'm looking for

Halp.

-Brett

Comment: Hello brettus. welcome to MSE. Can you please provide more details on your question? For example, are you looking for all four falling on those exact dates, or are you just looking for overlap between your mother and your friends mother (and similarly with father)? Also can you please include your thoughts on the problem/what you think the answer should be?

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for following up. I'm looking for the probability of all 4 falling on those exact dates. As for what the answer should be, I haven't a clue! It seems like the probability of that happening would be quite small.

Comment: Prob(someone's birthday falling on some particular date) = $\frac{1}{365}$ (discounting leap years). Prob(someone's birthday falling on some particular date,second person falling on second date) = Prob(someone's birthday falling on some particular date)$\times$Prob(second person falling on second date)... which can then be extended to 4 people

Comment: Is it important that the fathers and mothers dates match up? Or is it okay if your father has a birthday matching your friends mother?

Comment: well, i suppose it doesn't matter. though i'd be curious to know the answer to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a problem you find a bit difficult it is sometimes easier to try to solve a simplified example.

Instead of birthdays, let us say that your parents are throwing dice. Let's call your father $f_1$, your mother $m_1$, and you friend's parents $f_2$ and $m_2$. If $f_1$ throws a 2 and $m_1$ throws a 5, then $f_2$ has to throw a 2 and $m_2$ has to throw a 5. The probability of this happening is
$$
\frac{1}{36}.
$$

If only one of the parents have to match, then the probability is: the probability that $f_1$ matches $f_2$ and $m_1$ matches $m_2$ which is 1/36, PLUS the probability that $f_1$ mathes $m_2$ and $m_1$ matches $f_2$ which is also 1/36, MINUS the probability that they all match together (because this has already been counted). This will happen every sixth time, so it is 1/216. So the probability of either parents matching a throw of the die is:
$$
\frac{2}{36} - \frac{1}{216}.
$$

To verify this, you can simulate 1 million dice tosses and count the results. One of the things that make answering questions about statistics and probability easier than many questions in mathematics - you can brute force the answer in a computer and check what you calculated! :)

Here is some R-code for running the simulation.

```
# Throwing a die
NSIM = 1000000
hit = rep(0, NSIM)
for (i in 1:NSIM) {
  bd = sample(1:6, size=4, replace = TRUE)
  f1 = bd[1] 
  m1 = bd[2]
  f2 = bd[3]
  m2 = bd[4]
  if (f1 == f2 & m1 == m2) {
    hit[i] = 1
  } 
} 
sum(hit)/NSIM
1/36

# Father and friend's mother (or vice-versa) can share 'die'
hit2 = rep(0, NSIM)
for (i in 1:NSIM) {
  bd = sample(1:6, size=4, replace = TRUE)
  f1 = bd[1] 
  m1 = bd[2]
  f2 = bd[3]
  m2 = bd[4]
  if (f1 == f2 & m1 == m2 | f1 == m2 & m1 == f2) {
    hit2[i] = 1
  } 
} 
sum(hit2)/NSIM
2/36 - 1/216  # Remove occurences when they all throw the same number
```

My results:

```
> sum(hit)/NSIM
[1] 0.027855
> 1/36
[1] 0.02777778
> sum(hit2)/NSIM  
[1] 0.050728  
> 2/36 - 1/216  # Remove occurences when they all throw the same number  
[1] 0.05092593
```

By extending this to birthdays, we get:
$$
\frac{1}{365^2} \approx 0.0000075
$$
when the birthdays have to match up. And when they can cross over:
$$
\frac{2}{365^2} - \frac{1}{365^3} \approx 0.0000149
$$

Simulating in R again. Did 100 million this time - took a while!

```
# Birthday simulations - using 1 to 365
NSIM = 100000000 # 100M simulations
# Fathers match and mothers match
hit = rep(0, NSIM)
# Father and friend's mother (or vice-versa) can share birthday
hit2 = rep(0, NSIM)
# Simulation
bdsim = matrix(sample(1:365, size=4*NSIM, replace = TRUE), ncol=4)
for (i in 1:NSIM) {
  bd = bdsim[i, 1:4] 
  f1 = bd[1] 
  m1 = bd[2]
  f2 = bd[3]
  m2 = bd[4]
  if (f1 == f2 & m1 == m2) {
    hit[i] = 1
  } 
  if (f1 == f2 & m1 == m2 | f1 == m2 & m1 == f2) {
    hit2[i] = 1
  } 
} 
sum(hit)/NSIM
1/365^2
sum(hit2)/NSIM
2/365^2 - 1/365^3  # Remove occurences when they all throw the same number
```

And to verify the theoretical results with the simulated results:

```
> sum(hit)/NSIM
[1] 7.62e-06
> 1/365^2
[1] 7.506099e-06
> sum(hit2)/NSIM
[1] 1.485e-05
> 2/365^2 - 1/365^3  # Remove occurences when they all throw the same number
[1] 1.499163e-05
```

Comment: Because the results have been simulated, they will never be completely correct, but they give an indication that the theoretical results are correct.

Comment: Hmm... Idk if $100,000,000$ simulations was enough. Might want to go a few 100 million more... lol I'm kidding, this goes to show that my attempt was *way* off

Comment: Wow...this is incredible. I can't thank you enough. One last dumb question since I'm just a lay person and can't even pretend to completely comprehend all of this: how could I simplify the answer so I can tell my friend that the probability of this happening is something like 1 in a gazilion. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @brettus: Oh, it's not that improbable. The probability is 1 in 133 225. The criss-cross case is one in 67 114 (roughly). Pretty rare!

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins: Since the probabilities are so small, it was difficult to verify! Even at 10M. But 100M did the trick! :-)

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins: And you weren't way off. You were quite close. Since we are matching dates, the first two can be whatever they like. And the next two dates have to match the first ones.

Comment: @CoveredInChocolate You saw my attempt at the probability of 2 pairs of shared birthdays though right (I deleted that part now)? I had 0.547%, that’s nowhere near $1.499163*10^{-05}$

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care about overlaps (you said "I'm looking for the probability of all 4 falling on those exact dates."), you take the probability your mom's birthday is April 10th, and multiply that by the probability your friend's mom's birthday is April 10th, then you multiply that by the probability your dad was born on July 4th, and multiply that by the probability your friend's dad was born on July 4th.

This means $\frac{1}{365}*\frac{1}{365}*\frac{1}{365}*\frac{1}{365} = (\frac{1}{365})^4 = 5.63*10^{-11}$ *very slim* (THIS IS EXCLUDING LEAP YEARS). Multiply by 100 to get a percent: $5.63*10^{-9}$%

Bear in mind, that since you said you only care about birthdays falling on specific dates, the probability your mom's b-days are April 10th, and dad's are July 4th, is ***THE EXACT SAME PROBABILITY*** of your mom's birthday being January 28th, your friend's mom's Decmber 2nd, your Dad's April 11th, and your friend's dad's being October 30th.

If you only care about 2 pairs of the same birthday, the probability would actually be higher than for any select birthday assigned (the probability above). The probability of 2 pairs of shared birthdays gets more complicated as well...

for that, you can now see @CoveredInChocolate's answer

**Fun fact:** if there's a group of 23 people, there's over a 50% chance that 2 or more of them share a birthday.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! How would one calculate the probability of 2 pairs of shared birthdays? I think that's the real answer I'm looking for.

Comment: I'll have to think about that one. If and when I come up with that answer, someone else probably will have.

Comment: I really appreciate you spending time on something so silly. But, it's a true story and a bit mind-blowing to me!

Comment: I do not think this is silly either, but that is extremely cool that your moms and dads share the same birthdays. I've never heard of a coincidence like that. That's one thing about probability though, you never realize just how likely things are until you really dig into it. Take flipping a coin for example, after flipping it heads 100 times in a row, someone would be astonished (including myself), and say "what are the chances!?".

Comment: ...The fact is, the chances you flip heads 100 times in a row is the same as flipping H,*then* T,*then* T,*then* H, *then* T,*then* H,*then* T,*then* T,*then* T... (*any* combination of 100 flips, where order matters). The reason I stress *then* is because the order matters (in the case of coin flipping). Whenever some pattern is recognized in the real world, we're programmed to think "what are the chances?".

Answer (score 0):

The probability the moms share a birthday is $1/{365}$ (approximately; this ignores leap years). 
The probability the dads share a birthday is $1/365$.

Since these two events are independent, the probability they both happen is $1/365^2$.